# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the issue in this part of code.

```
public void HoverOnAElement(WebElement elementtoHoverOn){
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(elementtoHoverOn).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what is `elementtoHoverOn` all about?

Comment: Hover on a  element which is webelement type.@FindBy(className = "export-main")
    public WebElement DownloadButton;

Comment: Instead of a comment can you update the main question with this info and the relevant HTML?

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace? Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: still it showing the ssame error